# Can't get wifi connection over 150Mbps!

Tags: wireless, router

I'm trying to connect to my new router at a speed of 300Mbps. My new wireless router accepts 300Mbps in 2.4Mhz and 450Mbps in 5Mhz. I'm testing right next to the router and I get 150Mbps top.

I'm pretty aware of what 150/300/450Mbps means in real life, but the thing is that connecting to 150Mbps won't give anything above 8MBps when transfering files over the network.

I tested all the same in Windows 7 and I can get links of 300Mbps (fluctuating, but very stable at that speed), whit 22MBps for file transfers.

Is there something I can do? Thank you!

Edit: adding some info from terminal commands

**uname -mr**

```
3.5.0-28-generic i686
```

**lsb_release -d**

```
Description: Ubuntu 12.10
```

**lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection [8086:4237]
Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1211]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
--
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:3624]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

**lsmod**

```
Module Size Used by
ipt_MASQUERADE 12664 0 
xt_state 12515 0 
ipt_REJECT 12486 0 
xt_tcpudp 12532 0 
nf_nat_h323 12810 0 
nf_conntrack_h323 51811 1 nf_nat_h323
nf_nat_pptp 12537 0 
nf_conntrack_pptp 13554 1 nf_nat_pptp
nf_conntrack_proto_gre 13581 1 nf_conntrack_pptp
nf_nat_proto_gre 12672 1 nf_nat_pptp
nf_nat_tftp 12421 0 
nf_conntrack_tftp 12818 1 nf_nat_tftp
nf_nat_sip 16946 0 
nf_conntrack_sip 24511 1 nf_nat_sip
nf_nat_irc 12543 0 
nf_conntrack_irc 13113 1 nf_nat_irc
nf_nat_ftp 12549 0 
nf_conntrack_ftp 13107 1 nf_nat_ftp
iptable_nat 12978 0 
nf_nat 20317 9 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_h323,nf_nat_pptp,nf_nat_proto_gre,nf_nat_tftp,nf_nat_sip,nf_nat_irc,nf_nat_ftp ,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack_ipv4 14081 3 iptable_nat,nf_nat
nf_conntrack 66308 18 ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_state,nf_nat_h323,nf_conntrack_h 323,nf_nat_pptp,nf_conntrack_pptp,nf_conntrack_proto_gre,nf_nat_tftp,nf_conntrack_tftp,nf_nat_sip,nf _conntrack_sip,nf_nat_irc,nf_conntrack_irc,nf_nat_ ftp,nf_conntrack_ftp,iptable_nat,nf_nat,nf_conntra ck_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv4 12650 1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
snd_hrtimer 12649 1 
vesafb 13478 1 
coretemp 13169 0 
arc4 12474 2 
joydev 17162 0 
hp_wmi 13617 0 
sparse_keymap 13659 1 hp_wmi
dm_multipath 22403 0 
iptable_filter 12707 1 
scsi_dh 14214 1 dm_multipath
xt_owner 12451 12 
ip_tables 17792 2 iptable_nat,iptable_filter
x_tables 21936 8 ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_state,ipt_REJECT,xt_tcpudp,iptable_nat,iptable_filter,xt_owner,ip_tables
snd_hda_codec_hdmi 31457 1 
uvcvideo 71278 0 
videobuf2_core 32071 1 uvcvideo
videodev 95842 2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc 12757 1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops 13213 1 videobuf2_vmalloc
ir_lirc_codec 12740 0 
lirc_dev 18671 1 ir_lirc_codec
microcode 18210 0 
ir_mce_kbd_decoder 12636 0 
ir_sanyo_decoder 12466 0 
snd_hda_codec_idt 59762 1 
ir_sony_decoder 12463 0 
ir_jvc_decoder 12460 0 
psmouse 84878 0 
serio_raw 13032 0 
ir_rc6_decoder 12460 0 
ir_rc5_decoder 12460 0 
ir_nec_decoder 12460 0 
lpc_ich 16926 0 
fglrx 2917043 243 
snd_hda_intel 32516 5 
snd_hda_codec 111548 3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep 13273 1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi 13133 0 
snd_pcm 80235 3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
btusb 17987 0 
snd_rawmidi 25383 1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event 14476 1 snd_seq_midi
rc_rc6_mce 12455 0 
snd_seq 51281 3 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ene_ir 17908 0 
jmb38x_ms 17178 0 
rc_core 21267 11 ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sanyo_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_r c5_decoder,ir_nec_decoder,rc_rc6_mce,ene_ir
rfcomm 37277 12 
snd_timer 24412 3 snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm,snd_seq
memstick 15843 1 jmb38x_ms
snd_seq_device 14138 3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
parport_pc 31969 0 
bnep 17708 2 
iwlwifi 348525 0 
wmi 18591 1 hp_wmi
snd 62146 21 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel ,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_s eq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
video 18895 0 
bluetooth 183270 22 btusb,rfcomm,bnep
ppdev 12818 0 
mac80211 461261 1 iwlwifi
hp_accel 25729 0 
lis3lv02d 19230 1 hp_accel
input_polldev 13649 1 lis3lv02d
soundcore 14600 1 snd
snd_page_alloc 14037 2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
cfg80211 175574 2 iwlwifi,mac80211
mac_hid 13038 0 
lp 13300 0 
parport 40754 3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
binfmt_misc 17261 1 
hid_generic 12485 0 
usbhid 41734 0 
hid 82179 2 hid_generic,usbhid
ahci 25497 3 
libahci 25938 1 ahci
r8169 55977 0 
firewire_ohci 35522 0 
sdhci_pci 18156 0 
sdhci 27831 1 sdhci_pci
firewire_core 57493 1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t 12628 1 firewire_core
dm_raid45 75358 0 
xor 26091 1 dm_raid45
dm_mirror 21666 0 
dm_region_hash 16013 1 dm_mirror
dm_log 18138 3 dm_raid45,dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
```

**iwconfig**

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11abgn ESSID:"Diegosolo5" 
Mode:Managed Frequency:5.18 GHz Access Point: A0:F3:C1:8F:93:6C 
Bit Rate=150 Mb/s Tx-Power=14 dBm 
Retry long limit:7 RTS thrff Fragment thrff
Power Managementn
Link Quality=61/70 Signal level=-49 dBm 
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:269 Invalid misc:1714 Missed beacon:0

lo no wireless extensions.

eth0 no wireless extensions.
```

**ifconfig**

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:26:9e:10:af:42 
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:8698 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:8698 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:792325 (792.3 KB) TX bytes:792325 (792.3 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:1e:65:82:f1:3a 
inet addr:192.168.0.101 Bcast:192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::21e:65ff:fe82:f13a/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:2302128 errors:0 dropped:144 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:680971 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:3308302832 (3.3 GB) TX bytes:69550481 (69.5 MB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Often something IPS's catch you out on, I'm guessing you put 8MB with the capital "*B*" intentionally?

There is a difference between megaBITS and megaBYTES, your ISP will say you will get a 150Mb/s connection speed which is roughly 10+/- MB/s (MegaBytes)

Comment: Hi, and thak you for answering. Yes! I used the capital B intentionally and I understand your answer, but (just to clear out) my issue isn't with any ISP, just internal LAN spped. Thank you!